# JMeter File Upload Scenario

Tags: testing, file-upload, jmeter, jmx

I am trying to create a HTTP request that send both Json and File.

Sample Payload format:

------WebKitFormBoundaryooARNALDyzj0QAAl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="case"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

{Json-Data}
------WebKitFormBoundaryooARNALDyzj0QAAl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="Test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

------WebKitFormBoundaryooARNALDyzj0QAAl--

Above one is the format of the Payload.

When I try to run the script the HTTP request failing , the reason is , the JSON part is removed only the file part is sent in a payload.

Payload sent in the request:

--mKcQTUa2-T28YDq4lnQyGCl8ksaViUMuIjO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="TestViewer.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<actual file content, not shown here>
--mKcQTUa2-T28YDq4lnQyGCl8ksaViUMuIjO--

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set up your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler like this:

[image]

and you will be able to see the request details without files contents in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and file content in [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) if needed:

[image]

Also be aware that you can just record your request using browser (or other application) and [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html).

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload & Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Comment: Hi , When I try like that , I got this java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\agathiyanv\Documents\Automation\JMeter\blob (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: well, you need to create the file called `blob` and put your JSON data there

Comment: Hi, I can able to upload both document and JSON. But the problem here is , the JSON which I am using have some variable. Currently,  each time while I am executing the script i am adding wait and changing each value and then resume the Script.

Comment: Is there any way to handle that scenario , like while sending the JSON it will change the variable with actual value.